# A customized npm script to compile, watch and server

Tags: express, npm, webpack

I'm trying to set up a project which makes use of express and react. And I'm trying to make the best use of [React-Slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) project to benefit from it as much as possible. But the thing is that my project needs to be served (on the server side) by a script which I wrote. That script will use express and possibly socket.io to server the client side.

I think this is a problem if I use projects like React-Slingshot since they come with their own server scripts which support hot reloading and stuff. I'm willing to give up the fancy functionality like hot reloading. But I need to keep the `--watch` functionality so each time some file is changed, the code is compiled without me restarting the whole server.

Right now, the script section of package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node tools/nodeVersionCheck.js",
    "setup": "node tools/setup/setupMessage.js && npm install && node tools/setup/setup.js",
    "remove-demo": "babel-node tools/removeDemo.js",
    "start-message": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "prestart": "npm run start-message",
    "start": "concurrently -k -r -s first \"npm run test:watch\" \"npm run open:src\" \"npm run lint:watch\"",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "open:dist": "babel-node tools/distServer.js",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "rimraf ./dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean-dist && npm run lint && npm run test",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && babel server -d dist --presets es2015,stage-2",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:CI": "babel-node tools/testCi.js",
    "test:cover": "npm run test -- --coverage ",
    "test:cover:CI": "npm run test:CI -- --coverage && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "open:cover": "npm run test:cover && opn ./coverage/lcov-report/index.html",
    "analyze-bundle": "babel-node ./tools/analyzeBundle.js"
  },
```

This is a modified version of what you can find in React-Slingshot. I've made a change so when I run `npm run build`, it builds the server code as well and terminates. It used to be like this:

```
   "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
```

Now, I'm trying to find a way to run my own server (i.e. `node temp/server.js`) while the rest of the code is compiled based on `--watch` as for my dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a package like [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch) also check [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-run-builds-on-file-changes-using-watch-with-npm-scripts)